# Assigning variables an alias in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So if I have this html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in course.people">

        <div>
            <span bg-bind="schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id].gradeAverage"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span bg-bind="schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id].bestGrade"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span bg-bind="schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id].worstGrade"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span bg-bind="schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id].numberOfClasses"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span bg-bind="schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id].year"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span bg-bind="schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id].timesFlunked"></span>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to access `schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id]` multiple times, which makes the code look pretty messy after a while. Is there some way to put something like `ng-alias="x=schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id]"` or something somewhere? So that I could just use `x.gradeAverage` where needed. Or some other method of making the HTML seem less messy?

Btw, the example HTML is completely arbitrary, I just made something up, but I hope you understand what I'm asking.

Comment: On your `ngRepeat` - `ng-init="x = schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id]"` - `x` inside that repeat scope will now reference that path.

Comment: @tymeJV: That makes the variables static though = if `schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id]` is changed in the scope that isn't reflected in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can set a scope variable for `currentSchool` and access as `currentSchool[person.id]`. Example:

```
//controller
$scope.currentSchool = $scope.schools[$scope.schools.currentSchool];

//HTML
<li ng-repeat="person in course.people">
    <div>
        <span ng-bind="currentSchool[person.id].gradeAverage"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span ng-bind="currentSchool[person.id].bestGrade"></span>
    </div>
    ...
</li>
```

That will shorten it a little. Also, is `schools.currentSchool === schools[schools.currentSchool]`? If that is the case then you could shorten it even more. Either way that data structure seems a little confusing.

Comment: The example I provided was just something I made up, I just wanted to illustrate the problem :)

Comment: Gotcha. In any case, creating a reference to the object that contains `person.id`s as keys is probably the shortest way to go. You could also create a directive that prints out that information, then inside your ngRepeat have `<div student-info="person"></div>` or something. That would clean up both the controller and the markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output all of the members of the person object, you can iterate over the properties like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in course.people">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in schools[schools.currentSchool][person.id]">
    <span ng-bind="value"></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/c9psDfNkh5LGR0eVjIHg?p=preview